# VF page redirecting on Section itself

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a simple VF page which queries related Contact records based on the current contact id. I had this page on the Contact Page layout so that I can see the related contacts of the contact we open.

On VF page by clicking on the Account name, it opens the account detail page in the section itself. How can I achieve standard functionality where clicking on the Account, redirects me to its detail page(on current browser and not in the section itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using an [`<apex:outputLink>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputLink.htm) component to connect to the Account? Adding the attribute `target="_parent"` to your `<apex:outputLink>` tag will ensure that the new page opens in the main browser tab, rather than in the embedded Visualforce pane.

Since you're using `<apex:column ... /.>`, you may want to switch to doing something like

```
<apex:column>
    <apex:outputLink target="_parent" value="{! URLFOR($Action.Account.View, c.AccountId) }">
        {! c.Account.Name }
    </apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
```

where `c` is the name of your Contact variable.

Comment: I am just using `<apex:column />` tag and I don't find target attribute for this. Any other work around?

Comment: Worked as expected. I have added `headerValue` to the column tag to get me what I wanted. Cheers.